# How to run a line of a file by python and get ouput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ant to read a line of a file and give it to python and get output. for example

I wrote:

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = 100
a == b-10 and b== c-100
```

In python:

```
file = open("new.txt")
run(file[0])
run(file[1])
run(file[2])
print(out(file[3]))
```

And I want True from the last line.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The last line,  a == b - 10 and b == c-100 does not evaluate to True since b != c-100,
but what i think you are looking for is this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:

    lines = [line for line in f.readlines()]
    exec(lines[0])
    exec(lines[1])
    exec(lines[2])
    print(eval(lines[3]))
```